# With Leaflet, is it possible to draw a line where each end has a different weight?

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I want to draw a tapering line (eg, beginning of the line stroke has weight 10, end of the line stroke has weight 1).

Is it possible to do that with a polyline and appropriate attributes, or do I have to use a polygon (elongated triangle)?

Comment: AFAIK SVG does not have variable stoke-width, so you have to construct a `path`